# How to use existing decorators in Zend Framework?

Tags: php, html, zend-framework, zend-form, zend-decorators

Following code:

```
$this->addElement('text', 'email', array(
    'label' => 'Your email address:',
));

$this->addElement('submit', 'submit', array(
    'label' => 'Sign Guestbook',
));
```

produces following HTML:

```
<form enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" action="" method="post">
    <dl class="zend_form">
        <dt id="email-label">
            <label for="email" class="optional">Your email address:</label>
        </dt>
        <dd id="email-element">
            <input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="" />
        </dd>

        <dt id="submit-label">
            &#160;
        </dt>
        <dd id="submit-element">
            <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Sign Guestbook" />
        </dd>
    </dl>
</form>
```

I know, I can write my own decorators, but I would like to know, how to use existing decorators, to create following HTML:

```
<form enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" action="" method="post">
    <div>
        <label for="email" class="optional">Your email address:</label>
        <input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="" class="my_class" />
    </div>

    <div>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Sign Guestbook" class="my_class" />
    </div>
</form>
```

No `<dl/>`, `<dt/>`, `<dd/>`, added `class` attribute.

For example, I know, how to remove surrounding `<dl/>` tag:

```
$this->addDecorator('FormElements')
     ->addDecorator('Form');
```

Are other changes possible *without* writing custom decorators?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This (append this array to your parameters array, which now consists of only one label option) should help with your email field:

```
'class' => 'my_class',
'decorators' => array(
    'ViewHelper',
    'Errors',
    'Label',
    array('HtmlTag', array('tag' => 'div'))
)
```

And the same without `Label` - for submit.

Comment: Heh, that's almost exactly the same as here: http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.form.elements.html#zend.form.elements.custom

Answer (score 1):

You can use the HtmlTag decorator and pass which tag to use as a parameter.

All available decorators are listed here: http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.form.standardDecorators.html